# Using a checkbox to change table row styling

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have a dynamically generated table of n rows with a checkbox in each row. How can I make that table row have a different background-color when its checkbox is checked?

I have no problem using jQuery if need be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, dead simple:

```
$("tr :checkbox").live("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", this.checked ? "#eee" : "");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ubowa6)

Basically what that does is identify checkboxes that are contained in a row, watch for clicks on them, and then use their state within the event handler to set the `background-color` CSS style on the row containing the checkbox.

Things to consider augmenting/modifying:

- I used [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in case the table is dynamic on the client (e.g., if you add or remove rows), although you may prefer to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) rooted in the table instead. If the table will be completely static, you might just use [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- The above hooks *all* checkboxes inside rows, which is probably more than you want. jQuery supports nearly all of [CSS3's selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and [a fair bit more](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), so you can craft the selector for the checkboxes to make it more narrow. A basic change would be to filter by class (`$("tr :checkbox.foo")` where "foo" is the class) or checkbox name (`$("tr :checkbox[name=foo]")`).
- As [Morten suggests below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516488/using-a-checkbox-to-change-table-row-styling/5516545#5516545), you might consider adding/removing a class rather than giving the CSS values directly in the code, as that helps decouple your script from your styling.

Comment: Upvote from me as I nicked your selectors (was using css class and parents instead of closest).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('tr :checkbox').live('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected_row_style');
});
```

Comment: And right back atcha, using a class rather than inline style. Better for decoupling.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("checkbox").live("click", function()
{ 
    if (this.checked) 
    {
       $(this).attr('background-color','#FFFFFF');
    }
    else
    {
       $(this).attr('background-color','#000000');
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to change the background of the input element instead of the parent cell/row? Also, you probably meant `$(this)` instead of `this` ?

Comment: @AJweb: The second time, yeah; the first one (`this.checked`) is correct. Also, @Alan, what happens when you *un*check?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out my mistakes, i was in too much hurry :)